# Catalyst: how to delete all another sessions when user has been authorized?

Tags: perl, session, authentication, catalyst

I'm using
[`Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication)
to authenticate users and
[`Catalyst::Plugin::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::Session)
to track sessions. Is it possible to solve my problem using these plugins?

When a user has been authorized at some place, other sessions (the same user on other platforms, browsers etc.) automatically change to invalid. There can be only one working session from this particular user at the same time.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by _another sessions automatically turns to invalid_? The user's old sessions on the same system? Different users' sessions? The user's sessions on other systems? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: You're asking for any open sessions on any other server from any other client to be logged out when a user logs in somewhere? That's a tall order. Do all the servers even know about and communicate with each other?

Comment: Actually, there is only one server. All I need is to logout user from another devices when he logs in from somewhere else.

Comment: I think it also depends on your underlying session storage layer. You could certainly add code that looks into the sessions and invalidates (i.e. deletes from storage) all the other ones associated to this user. But it would be implementation-specific.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought there is kinda "generic" methods or even a special options in config...